# Is installation of SQLite required for every machine that uses it?

Tags: sqlite, installation, precompiled-binaries

Good morning,

I have developed a program that uses SQLite, and I'd like to share it with another computer. But not to share connection to the SQLite database (I know that a server/client would do that a lot better), just to send it to another computer with the compiled program to use it from there. I am wondering if I can do that without download the prebuilt binaries on every machine, or if they are not needed for executing the program ?

http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html :

> Get a copy of the prebuilt binaries for your machine, or get a copy of the sources and compile them yourself.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does your program actually *use* the prebuilt binaries?

Comment: Well, that is actually my question. Let me rephrase it: does any program that uses SQLite always also use the prebuilt binaries? Or is it only useful for some tasks, meaning that it is not always required to have it installed on a computer that use SQLite trhough a program ?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about how your program accesses the SQLite library?